# German discount brokers that don't claim fund's periodic kickback payments

Tags: germany, broker, charges, discount-broker

In Germany, it's legal for an investment fund to pay your securities account provider a yearly provision.
Basically it's a form of kickback payment, i.e. one where your broker that provides you your securities account is incentivized to recommend you funds with higher provisions and hold on to those funds, even if they perform poorly.

With traditional managed funds such provisions are relatively common, but with ETFs they aren't.

Brokers are free to waive these provisions, i.e. they may decide to not participate in that scheme and simply forward those payments to your margin account.

Are there any discount brokers on the german market who actually do this?

Comment: Those kickbacks are usually used to offer free trades. Do you mean, you plan to bascially e.g. pay 4€ (or 0€) fees and get 5€ (or 1€) kickback back to you? Otherwise, noone forces you to buy a bad etf just because your broker recommends it. The broker wants to earn money somewhere, so if not by recommending bad etfs (that you can avoid by just buying a better etf), they may earn money with someting you cannot avoid.

Comment: @Solarflare I think those kickbacks really are only a thing with actively managed funds, i.e. I'm not aware of any ETF that pays them. Also, some actively managed funds have a long history of paying kickbacks, i.e. long before discount brokers were a thing. For example, where your broker already charges you like 20 - 60 € flat for your account, plus a relative charge of - say - 0.25 % of the securities you own plus 1 to 1.5 % or so order provisions. The yearly kickbacks paid by funds are on top and are in the order of 0.5 to 1 %.

Comment: @Solarflare Of course, nobody is being forced to follow bad advice. I guess I'm asking in case I'll come across some actively managed fund that performs well and better than an equivalent ETF and that also happens to pay kickbacks (that I would be happy to get for myself on top). Also, if there are brokers who distinguish themselves from others by not participating in this questionable kickback game that information arguably can be seen as a good marker for their general service quality. Btw, it's only since a few years that brokers must disclose the amount of kickbacks they receive, yearly.